# Is Python a good choice for computer vision?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm about to start a computer vision project which will deal with image segmentation things and I'm looking for a good programming development environment.

Is there any warmly suggested programming language for computer vision?

My choice would be Python together with the openCV library but I'm not sure if this is a good choice: python is slow and it looks like it isn't meant for computer vision (few library and support).

I love this language but I personally don't feel it right for this purpose.

Comment: You could always write it in Python, then optimize your bottlenecks in C/C++ extensions...

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128562)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is used for several production Computer Vision systems. Good libraries like OpenCV, excellent performance, easy to put into a production environment. If you need to do machine learning, there are many libraries out there (LibSVM / SVMlight, Torch). If you have to resort to "loop on all pixels" code it will perform well.

MATLAB is also an idea, but considering the performance advantages of C++... and the fact that MATLAB syntax is pretty foreign to most tried-and-true C/Java - "learnt" programmers, it may not be nearly as good an option.